# Replace double/nested for loop over function that returns dataframe with apply in R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, apply, mapply

Consider a function that takes in two input arguments and returns a dataframe:

```
myFun <- function(a, b){
   data.frame(aSQ = a^2, bSQ = b^2, SQPROD = a^2*b^2)
}

myFun(1, 1)
```

A double loop can be constructed over each of the arguments of this function:

```
results <- as.data.frame(matrix(0, nrow = 9, ncol = 3, 
                         dimnames = list(c(), c('aSQ', 'bSQ', 'SQPROD'))))
for (a in 1:3)
   for (b in 1:3)
      results[(a-1)*3+b, ] <- myFun(a, b)
```

How to replace this double loop with an apply construct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
resList <- mapply(
   myFun,
   a = rep(1:3, times = 3), 
   b = rep(1:3, each  = 3), 
   SIMPLIFY = FALSE
)

dplyr::bind_rows(resList)
```

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-if-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking

Comment: May I not agree with this kind of behavior, even though?

Comment: Well, I think self-answering is fine but opinions differ. Anyway, I see no evil intentions, here.